# Rounding Corners of UITextField in ViewDidLoad only affects the left corners

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield, viewdidload

i am trying to round the top and the bottom border of two UITextField

The result in `ViewDidLoad()`

[image: ViewDidLoad Result]

The result in `ViewDidAppear`

[image: ViewDidAppear Result]

The problem is `ViewDidAppear` makes the border changes after half a sec of loading the view which is not good in my situation ,

any one knows why it's only rounding the left corner in `ViewDidLoad` method ?

any suggestions appreciated ?

*** Update ***

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the same as `ViewDidLoad`

Here is the code i use to round the corners

```
extension UITextField {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

And

```
self.FirstTextField.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.TopRight | UIRectCorner.TopLeft, radius: 10.0)
self.SecondTextField.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight, radius: 10.0)
```

Comment: how did you setup the text fields

Comment: in StoryBoard using AutoLayout

Comment: Did you set the constraints correctly? That's most likely the issue

Comment: The constraints is all ok , i thought the same way , but i found that the problem is in rounding the corners

Comment: @Aladin take a look at the update

Comment: @Panda check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one thing that i have ever expected to fix this is to dispatch on the main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
      self.FirstTextField.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.TopRight | UIRectCorner.TopLeft, radius: 10.0)
      self.SecondTextField.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.BottomRight, radius: 10.0)
});
```

Now i don't know if this can be inefficient or not but yeah it works :D

if any one has a better Answer please post it :)

Comment: This is actually what you're supposed to do if you need to update the UI from somewhere other than the main thread (e.g. downloading an image). Where were you calling the method from before?

Comment: i was calling it normally

Comment: I had to do it like this too, making the changes in `viewWillAppear` didn't do anything, and watching an image form into a circle after the interface loaded in `viewDidAppear` is absolutely tacky. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your code of rounding the text fields to `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Same result as `ViewDidLoad`  see the updated question the only difference is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` works fine if you rotat the device once  @Aladin

Comment: You mean `viewWillLayoutSubviews` ? @Aladin

Comment: ViewControllers only has `viewWillLayoutSubviews ` so you mean it , but unfortunately same as `ViewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` @Aladin

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the layer mask to its bounds

`self.layer.masksToBounds = true`

EDIT:

Try using & instead of |, I believe it's take only the first corner since you used or.

```
self.FirstTextField.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.TopRight & UIRectCorner.TopLeft, radius: 10.0)
self.SecondTextField.roundCorners(UIRectCorner.BottomLeft & UIRectCorner.BottomRight, radius: 10.0)
```

Comment: You are thinking the same way i am thinking :) , i tried this before but it didn't round any corners at all :)) :D

Comment: Argh, I'm out of ideas than, sorry!

Comment: i am stuck too can't figure it out , it's blowing my mind , but no problem i hope any one will help soon , thanks for trying to help :) @David

Comment: Look i got an idea and it works fine , check my answer